# How to find all class properties that start with a lower case letter

Tags: c#, regex

In Visual Studio 2019, how do I Find (`Ctrl + F`, using Regular Expressions option) all class properties that start with a lower case?

```
public decimal FirstName { get; set; }  
public decimal lastName { get; set; }
```

In sample above, I would only want `lastName` to be highlighted

The following selects everything except what I'm looking for...

```
public .*?\s[a-z]?
```

Not really how I want to solve it though.

Answer (score 1):

Based just on the code snippet you provided, you may try:

```
public \S+ [a-z]\w+ \{.*?\}
```

If the content inside the brackets might span multiple lines, then you can enable dot all mode.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
(\b[a-z]\w+\b)(?=\s{.*})
```

[**demo**](https://regex101.com/r/HdN3eD/1)